# How to encrypt a mail in Thunderbird?

Tags: encryption, thunderbird, arch-linux, openpgp

I have been using PGP for a long time now but recently [Thunderbird replaced the Enigmail encryption-plugin with a native PGP solution](https://blog.thunderbird.net/2019/10/thunderbird-enigmail-and-openpgp/).

That's maybe good news, however, I cannot figure out how to manage keys and encrypt messages. First of all, I received a signed message and I wanted to fetch the PGP key from the keyservers. It would show me the entire fingerprint and allow to click something called *"Accepted (unverified)"* but it would not import the key and always tell me *"Key import failed."*

So, I took it to the command-line and fetched the key from the SKS Keyservers pool:

```
❯ gpg --keyserver pool.sks-keyservers.net --search-key 0xB██████████████7
gpg: data source: http://85.230.80.174:11371
(1) CCC ██████████ (Key 2020) <m█████████@ccc.de>
    CCC-██████████ (Key 2020) <m█████████████@ccc.de>
    CCC ██████████ (CCC ██████████, Key 2020) <o█████@ccc.de>
      4096 bit RSA key B██████████████7, created: 2020-03-21, expires: 2021-03-31
Enter number(s), N)ext, or Q)uit > 1
gpg: key B██████████████7: public key "CCC-██████████ (Key 2020) <m█████████████@ccc.de>" imported
gpg: Total number processed: 1
gpg:               imported: 1
```

But, oof, apparently, there is no way to import local PGP keys into Thunderbird, so I had to dump the public key into a file `gpg --export --armor 0xB██████████████7 > /tmp/foo` and import it manually through the Thunderbird key manager from that file.

Now, Thunderbird recognizes the key and I'm able to verify the signature. But when I try to respond to that mail, I simply won't be able to activate any security feature.

[image: screenshot of the key manager]

Thunderbird message security settings still tell me the key is *"not found"* even though the Thunderbird OpenPGP key manager lists the very same key.

I tried reloading the key cache of the Thunderbird OpenPGP key manager and also restarted the entire software. I still have no option to enable security when responding to that mail, even though it recognizes the valid signature.

How do I properly encrypt a mail in Thunderbird? Is there any step-by-step walk-through?

Or, alternatively, should I try to force-install the old Enigmail plugin which used to work reliably for years?

*Edit 0: Sorry, it's Thunderbird 78 on Arch Linux.*

[image: thunderbird version]

*Edit 1: GnuPG version (but as far as I understand, it's not used by Thunderbird):*

```
❯ gpg --version
gpg (GnuPG) 2.2.27
libgcrypt 1.9.1-unknown
```

*Edit 2: Thunderbird appears to be properly configured. I can decrypt messages and verify signatures. I just cannot encrypt.*

Answer (score 0):

The article
[Thunderbird:OpenPGP:2020](https://wiki.mozilla.org/Thunderbird:OpenPGP:2020)
has this information:

> The Thunderbird 68.x branch, which will be actively maintained until autumn 2020, will be the last versions that supports Enigmail.
> ...
> Users who already own secret keys from their previous use of Enigmail and GnuPG, and who wish to reuse their existing secret keys, will be required to transfer their keys to Thunderbird 78. **On systems that have GnuPG installed, we might be able to offer assisted importing**.

One option is to remain with Thunderbird 68 and Enigmail until the new code
is stabilized. The current OpenPGP implementation in Thunderbird 78
still sounds to me more like a Beta version.

To use Thunderbird 78, read with attention the article
[Thunderbird:OpenPGP:Migration-From-Enigmail](https://wiki.mozilla.org/Thunderbird:OpenPGP:Migration-From-Enigmail).
In case of a problem, you should contact the Mozilla devs to file a bug report.